# Establishing page load time

Tags: asp-classic

How would you go about printing on the bottom of a page, produced by ASP, the time taken by ASP to process the page.

Thanks,

Barry

Comment: This looks promising: http://clutteredcode.blogspot.com/2009/07/showing-page-load-time-asp.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have these two library functions loaded ( or included ) in your page

```
sub StartTimer(x)
   StopWatch(x) = timer
end sub


function StopTimer(x)
   EndTime = Timer
   'Watch for the midnight wraparound...
   if EndTime < StopWatch(x) then
     EndTime = EndTime + (86400)
   end if
   StopTimer = EndTime - StopWatch(x)
end function
```

you can go something like this;

```
<%option explicit%>
<!--#include virtual='/yourlibraryfunctionsfile_whichincludes_the_above_two_functions.asp'-->
<%
Dim StopWatch(1)
'start timer
StartTimer x

'do your time taking code here

'end timer
elapsed_time = StopTimer(x)

'print out how much that elapsed time is
response.write elapsed_time
%>
```

If you want to learn it in depth, read [this 4guysfromrolla article](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020203250/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/122799-1.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

Look how to get the earliest server request and then the latest client request.
Subtract one DateTime from another. Good Luck!